# How can i get VK video direct links on client-side?

Tags: html5-video, vk

I want to play VK videos with a HTML5 player through client-side generated direct video links. I've seen some sites are doing it. Like this: http://www.jethdfilmizle.com/veka.swf?file=vk.com%2Fvideo_ext.php%3Foid%3D189406059%26id%3D163663575%26hash%3D388c8150742ccb2f&otobaslat=0

But this one probably created with ActionScript and I don't want AS or Adobe Flash. I need client-side direct link for HTML5 player.